# SQLite store ListView object in TextViews

Tags: android, android-sqlite, textview

I have a SQLite Database that stores contacts in an arraylist. This arraylist is then used to create objects and add them to a listview. When i try and click on an item using the listener, the Textviews that are set to contain nothing. After checking with a log, all the textviews contain null values for some reason. I'm assuming that the onClick is not pulling any information from the database but i don't know how to resolve the problem. Does anyone know what's doing wrong. Thanks. Please excuse the excessive commenting.

Method used onCreate to populate list view (holds the listener)

```
public void fillContactsList()
   {    
        // Call method to get all contact entries.
        db.getAllContacts();

        // Defines listview.
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Create adapter using entries from database.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactList);        

        // Set adapter in listView.
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Listener for when the user clicks a contact object.
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                /* 
                 Shows the dialog box containing the user details 
                 and any operations that they may wish to perform.
                */
                contactsView();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }           
        });     
    }
```

Dialog that contains textviews

```
public  void contactsView()
    {       
         // Define alert dialog.
         AlertDialog.Builder contactView = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

         // Define inflater.
         LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

         // Set the view  to inflate the dialog_view xml file.
         final View contactDetailsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);

         // TextView variables.
         viewNameValue = (TextView) contactDetailsView.findViewById(R.id.viewName);
         viewMobNoValue = (TextView) contactDetailsView.findViewById(R.id.viewMobNo);
         viewEmailValue = (TextView) contactDetailsView.findViewById(R.id.viewEmail);
         viewPostcodeValue = (TextView) contactDetailsView.findViewById(R.id.viewPostcode);
         viewDateOfBirthValue = (TextView) contactDetailsView.findViewById(R.id.viewDateOfBirth);
         viewAdditionalInformationValue = (TextView) contactDetailsView.findViewById(R.id.viewAdditionalInformation);

         // TextView variables (shows the user their details).
         viewNameValue.setText(contact.getName());
         viewMobNoValue.setText(contact.getPhoneNumber());
         viewEmailValue.setText(contact.getEmail());
         viewPostcodeValue.setText(contact.getPostcode());
         viewDateOfBirthValue.setText(contact.getDateOfBirth());
         viewAdditionalInformationValue.setText(contact.getAdditionalInformation());

         // Adds a title to the dialog box.
         contactView.setTitle("Contact Details")

         // Sets dialog view to the layout provided by dialog_view xml file.
         .setView(contactDetailsView)  

         // Button used to allow the user to stop viewing their details.
         .setPositiveButton(R.string.go_back, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

             }
         })

         // Button used to allow the user to delete their details.
         .setNeutralButton(R.string.delete_contact, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 contactOptionsDelete();
             }
         })

         // Button used to allow the user to edit their details.
         .setNegativeButton(R.string.edit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 contactOptionsEdit();
             }
         });

         // Creates the AlertDialog.
         contactView.create();

         // Displays the AlertDialog.
         contactView.show();
    }
```

Method used to fill listview

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select query to get all data.
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // Clears the list (prevents duplication when used in onCreate / onResume).
        MainActivity.contactList.clear();

        // Loops through all rows, adding to the list.
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();

                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
                contact.setPostcode(cursor.getString(4));
                contact.setDateOfBirth(cursor.getString(5));
                contact.setAdditionalInformation(cursor.getString(6));

                // Adds contact to the array list.
                String name = cursor.getString(1) +"\n"+ cursor.getString(2) +"\n"+ cursor.getString(3)
                              +"\n"+ cursor.getString(4) +"\n"+ cursor.getString(5) +"\n"+ cursor.getString(6);
                MainActivity.contactList.add(name);

                // contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // Returns the contact list.
        return contactList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming that the ....

Did you verify ?

Complete your coding with some debug statements and you will see it in LogCat. ( assuming you are using eclipse ) 
An alternative is, to set some breakpoints and to trace through the program. 
This I am doing, if the debug statements can't give all the answers.

// hans